# React: invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, frontend

My React application works fine until I was trying to use react-cart-components and add this line `<Cart currency="CAD" />`

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The funny thing is that this application works fine on my friend's computer and it can be successfully deployed on heroku, but it is not working on my computer. I have already checked my versions of react-dom and react-native and they are newest, and there is only one copy of React in my app, everything is fine. Any ideas?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ToolBox from 'components/ToolBox';
import Product from 'components/Product';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'css/products.scss';
import { Cart, AddCartButton } from 'react-cart-components'

.........

const Products = () => {

.........

return (
    <div>
        <ToolBox  search={search} />
        <Cart currency="CAD" />
        <div className="products">
            <div className="columns is-multiline ">
                {
                    currentPage.map(pdct => {
                        return (
                            <div className="column is-2" key={pdct.productId}>
                                <Product product={pdct} />

                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>        
)
```

This is my friend's package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.21",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react-cart-components": "^2.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "twilio": "^3.47.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.1"
```

The following is mine

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.21",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-cart-components": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "twilio": "^3.47.0",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: have you tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that

Comment: Are you and your friend using the same package-lock.json as well as same package.json. Your project might have a react dependency of different version which might causing the issue. Make sure your package-lock.json files are also the same.

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies please?

Comment: I don't see any hook calls in that code.

Comment: I have posted my and my friend's package.json. Actually, my and my friend's project are both cloned from the same Github project so they are supposed to be the same. The reason why the package.json are a little bit different is that I was trying to fix this problem.

Comment: In the beginning , I used class component and it works fine until I add 'react-cart-component' into my application. After the error "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." occurred, I changed it to a functional component, but the condition is still the same